# awk command not executed within bash script but works fine on the commandline

Tags: bash, awk

I am new to bash scripting. I am trying to run the following script :

```
#! /bin/bash

#the following command runs fine within the bash script
awk>/home/Bash_Scripts/filename1 -F, '$3!="constant"{print}' /home/Bash_Scripts/logs.csv

# THE FOLLOWING COMMAND WORKS FINE FROM COMMAND LINE BUT NOT FROM WITHIN BASH SCRIPT

/usr/bin/awk -f /home/Bash_Scripts/process.awk /home/Bash_Scripts/filename1
```

Can someone please explain why? Both are awk commands. One works only from commandline and not from within the bash script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not enough details: what errors do you see?

Comment: Where there's lack of information or lack of effort from the OP, there will be lack of responses. Anyone could have helped in a heartbeat if there was enough information.

Comment: Show your `/home/Bash_Scripts/process.awk`

Comment: Execute the commands and copy/paste your display so we can see what you're doing and what error message you're getting, if any.

Comment: A space between **awk** and **>** might help.

Answer (score 1):

Three points:

1. You are using `/home/Bash_Scripts/filename1` as you output file in the script but as input file in the command line
2. `/home/Bash_Scripts/logs.csv` is your input file in the script.
3. You use `/usr/bin/awk` in the command line but just `awk` in the script.  This is backwards to what is normally done as you know what `PATH` is set to in the command line but no idea in general for a script.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. But it still doesnt explain why process.awk is not executed from within the script. process,awk is a simple awk program that adds values of 2 fields in the input file. This line works perfectly fine from the command line : /usr/bin/awk -f /home/Bash_Scripts/process.awk /home/Bash_Scripts/filename1 but not from within the script. There are no erros. It simply is not executed.I dont see the values printed when I run the script from within the script

Comment: Solved it. Thanks. I just used '<' operator for the inout file./usr/bin/awk -f /home/Bash_Scripts/process.awk <  /home/Bash_Scripts/filename1